# _winreg CreateKey function in Python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, winreg

I have a piece of code that creates a registry key and changes value in it. Although it work perfectly fine in my system but it fails when ran on any other system.

```
keyVal= r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies'
key2change= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
CreateKey(key2change,keyVal+"\System")

key2change= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal+"\System",0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
SetValueEx(key2change, "Wallpaper", 0, REG_SZ, picName)
SetValueEx(key2change, "WallpaperStyle", 0, REG_SZ, "0")
```

This doesn't create the "System" key in other PC thus no value is changed.
Also I am using Windows 7 x64 bit and I am packaging the code using pyinstaller.

Comment: Permission issue maybe? What happens if you run as administrator?

Comment: Nothing happens. Also I am using HKCU thus administrator privileges doesn't seems to be required.

Comment: Try changing all the `"\System"` literals into `r"\System"`.

Comment: I did but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did worked out for me.

```
keyVal= r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies'
key2change= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
CreateKey(key2change,keyVal+"\System", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

key2change= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal+"\System",0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
SetValueEx(key2change, "Wallpaper",0,REG_SZ, "D:\\test.jpg")
SetValueEx(key2change, "WallpaperStyle",0,REG_SZ, "2")
```